# .NET C#/VB.NET How to access Form Controls from Module

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

This may sound like stupid question.

How do I do something like this.

```
Module Misc
    Public Sub WriteLog(ByVal txt As String)
        Form1.TextBox3.Text += txt + vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Module
```

This is inside the Module separate from Form1 class as you can see right off the bat it's not a class and there is no reference to Form1.. how do I access Form1 without passing reference to make factory modules work like this. This is to be used for purposes like threading functions and helper function all around the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access a class without a reference to an instance of that class. Your best bet might be something like this:

```
Module Module1
    Private m_MyForm As Form1
    Public ReadOnly Property MyForm() As Form1
        Get
            If IsNothing(m_MyForm) Then m_MyForm = New Form1
            Return m_MyForm
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub WriteLog(ByVal txt As String)
        MyForm.TextBox3.Text += txt + vbNewLine
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now anywhere in your application you can access Form1 using Module1.MyForm.

**Note: This limits you to having only one instance of Form1 which will persist until the application exits.**

Comment: This is good.. but worse in my case... hmmm, how I use both Form1.. and Module1 :\